# What is the default audio stream of TTS?

Tags: android, text-to-speech, android-audiomanager

As far as I can tell, there are currently are 7 audio streams in [Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html):

```
STREAM_ALARM         (for alarms)
STREAM_DTMF          (for DTMF Tones)
STREAM_MUSIC         (for music playback)
STREAM_NOTIFICATION  (for notifications)
STREAM_RING          (for the phone ring)
STREAM_SYSTEM        (for system sounds)
STREAM_VOICE_CALL    (for phone calls)
```

I also know that it is possible to *explicitly* tell the TTS engine which stream to use:

```
params.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_STREAM, String.valueOf(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM));
mTts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, params);
```

What I couldn't find, however, is what stream is used by default when I **don't** specify an audio stream.

What is the default audio stream from Android's TextToSpeech engine?

Is there a way to query which stream is *currently* being used by Android's TextToSpeech engine?

**UPDATE:** `TextToSpeech.Engine` has a constant defined as [DEFAULT_STREAM](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.Engine.html#DEFAULT_STREAM) but it is unclear which of the 7 streams it is referring to. It has the same hex value (0x3) as STREAM_MUSIC, though. Is this it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`STREAM_MUSIC` is the default in the AOSP source, defined in [TextToSpeech.java](http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.java&l=164) (line 164 as of this writing) in `frameworks/base.git`:

```
/**
 * Default audio stream used when playing synthesized speech.
 */
public static final int DEFAULT_STREAM = AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC;
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much. +51. Do you also happen to know the answer to this related question? [TTS output always going to A2DP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963461/tts-output-always-going-to-a2dp)

Comment: Don't know off-hand, but I've added a bounty to the question.