# Text-to-Speech does not speak during a call on Samsung S3

Tags: android, bluetooth, text-to-speech, samsung-mobile, google-text-to-speech

I have an application with multiple Google TTS prompts and using it with Bluetooth headsets including during voice calls. TTS is working fine on all devices except **Samsung S3**. On this device I could not hear TTS prompts, but logs are showing that everything in ok, even `onUtteranceCompleted()` callback is called after end of speech.
Any ideas?

Comment: Which stream type are you using?

Comment: Nothing special. Just using `mTts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, params);` method

Comment: See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963461/tts-output-always-going-to-a2dp) is going to help.