# Android TTS with HFP profile

Tags: android, text-to-speech, android-bluetooth, a2dp

I want to use my headset with hfp and stream TTS to the headset without using the a2dp profile.

1) I init audio manager:

```
audio = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audio.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
```

2) I pair the device using reflection:

```
Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createBond", (Class[]) null);

Object invokeResult = m.invoke(device, (Object[]) null);
```

3) when I receive the intent BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED and the new state is BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED I bind to the headset using the IBluetoothHeadset android interface.

```
mContext.bindService(new Intent(IBluetoothHeadset.class.getName()), mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)
```

4) in the `onServiceConnected` implementation I invoke:

```
boolean connectResult = mService.connect(headset);
```

5) if `connectResult` is true, I init audio:

```
audio.setBluetoothScoOn(on);
audio.startBluetoothSco();
```

But, when I call:

```
tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
```

the audio is not redirected to the headset.

Note: in this case audio.isBluetoothA2dpOn() returns false.

I successfully redirect the audio ONLY if I previously paired the device using android system. In that case `audio.isBluetoothA2dpOn(`) returns true.

Is there any way to use TTS with HFP profile?

I already tried this solution but it didn't work for me

[TTS output always going to A2DP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963461/tts-output-always-going-to-a2dp)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try SoundAbout in Google Play. It has TTS settings that allow routing audio to Bluetooth mono (HFP).