# How to mute a Youtube Video by using Youtube API v3?

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I'm using **Youtube Api V3** for playing a video in my **android App**. However, I'm using Text to speech along with the video, so I would like to **mute** the video so that the other audio is audible.

I've searched the documentation and internet, but found solution only for javascript. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I've looked at the Youtube API for Android and haven't seen any volume controls. What I've seen on the Android documentation tho is the native method [setCurrentVolume](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/VolumeProvider.html) under the [VolumeProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/VolumeProvider.html) object.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But does that also reduce the volume of the TextToSpeech voice also ?

Comment: not familiar, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Still haven't found the exact solution to mute the Youtube Video using the Api.

Instead, Here's the **work-around solution** I've reached, in my case. Hope it might be helpful for someone else.

I've set the TTS Stream to STREAM_ALARM.(refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877272/what-is-the-default-audio-stream-of-tts) question)

```
HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_STREAM, String.valueOf(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM));

textToSpeech.speak("Hello World", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, params);
```

Now I Mute the SREAM_MUSIC Volume and I got the result I wanted. Anyone got better Ideas are more than welcome.

```
setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
if (am != null) {
    am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The YouTube Data API v3 has nothing to do with playback, as the name implies it is used only for accessing YouTube's data.

If you want to mute a video you have to do that on a YouTubePlayer of some sort.
[This](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/) is the official YouTube player from Google. I am not sure you can mute the volume with this though, probably not.

[Android-YouTube-Player](https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/Android-YouTube-Player) is an alternative player, it is easier to use and you can change the volume programmatically.

```
YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView = findViewById(R.id.youtube_player_view);

youTubePlayerView.initialize(new YouTubePlayerInitListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInitSuccess(final YouTubePlayer initializedYouTubePlayer) {    
        initializedYouTubePlayer.addListener(new AbstractYouTubePlayerListener() {
            @Override
            public void onReady() {
                String videoId = "6JYIGclVQdw";
                initializedYouTubePlayer.loadVideo(videoId, 0);
                initializedYouTubePlayer.setVolume(0);
            }
        });        
    }
}, true);
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. I've already tried your youtube-player (omg. You're the author !!) and some other based on webview, but couldn't get it to work (maybe I was using the latest android version emulator). I realized that the webview based youtube implementations has got volume control. Finally resolved to using the above workaround.

Comment: @MonsterBrain WebView based implementations usually have problems running on emulators. I think it has something to do with graphics drivers.