# Android YouTubePlayer should start video with mute sound

Tags: android, android-youtube-api, youtubeplayer

I am using **YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi-1.2.2** and showing a youtube video for some marketing tasks.

I need the video to autostart on loading but has to be muted initially and after user interaction, it will get unmuted.

I have explored all the available options but not able to get any direction to get this done.

This could be easily done in iOS with JavaScript customization.

Comment: Have you seen this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49828580/821110?

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.