# How to mute embed youtube video in youtubeplayerview

Tags: java, android, xml, youtube-api

I am using Youtube Api for playing videos in my app, video is playing fine but i want to mute the video programmatically. I searched a lot about it but i am not finding anything for disable the sound of video.
Please help me and tell me the solution to mute the YouTube video.

This is my code:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    myouTubePlayerView = findViewById(R.id.utube_video);

    myurl = "haE1BA1joxg";
    monInitializedListener = new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
            youTubePlayer.loadVideo(myurl);
        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

        }
    };

    myouTubePlayerView.initialize(YoutubeConfig.getApiKey(), monInitializedListener);
}
```

Comment: Possibly related answers: [How to mute a Youtube Video by ...?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49789660/295004)

Comment: i have checked this.. but he used youtubeplayerview.initialize(new YouTubePlayerInitListener) and i am not finding any method of this name.

Comment: That answer is for the alternate player 'Android-YouTube-Player' not YouTubePlayer API, check other answer for possible workaround.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for YouTube Player API, under that documentation you can find this:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_controls

```
player.mute():Void
```

Is the API call for muting the video.